# Automatic Backups are they performed with Instance off

Tags: google-cloud-sql

Is automatic Backup performed regardless of the Cloud SQL instance State?

we want to stop the instance dayly so we can keep costs to the minimum

Answer (score 1):

Automatic backups are not taken if the instance is off.